# IntelliJ generated Ant build overwrites my MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant

I have a simple project in IntelliJ where i go to *Project structure -> Artifacts -> Add Jar from modules with dependencies -> copy to the output directory and link via manifest (manifest is placed in %ProjectDir%/resources/manifests/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) -> OK -> OK*

Now, if I run `make`, the jar will be placed under `out/artifacts` and if I look inside the jar and open up the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file it contains the correct Class-Path information. If I then go back into IntelliJ, generate an ant build and run it, the contents of META-INF/MANIFEST.MF inside the compiled jar now looks like this:

`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_80-b15 (Oracle Corporation)`

As you can see the `Class-Path` entry has been completely removed, and this prevents me from being able to use the jar from somewhere else.

So my question is: Does anyone know why the ant build generated by intellij overwrites the MANIFEST.MF that is otherwise used by the built-in `make`functionality in intellij?

I might also add that I generate this ant build because I want to do some simple stuff like copying the built jar to a different location after compilation.

**EDIT**:

If I manually change the `<jar ... filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">` to `<jar ... filesetmanifest="merge">` in the generated ant script, at least the `Class-Path` from my original MANIFEST.MF appears in the MANIFEST.MF that gets copied into the jar file. However, I would really like to avoid having to manually change the generated ant script in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the -m option. To see a list of available JAR option, type jar with no arguments and output will provide a list of arguments and example. In your case, you may need to modify some of the Ant or IntelliJ commands to generate the JAR with provided MANIFEST.MF file.

```
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfmn0PMe] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] files ...
Options:
    -c  create new archive
    -t  list table of contents for archive
    -x  extract named (or all) files from archive
    -u  update existing archive
    -v  generate verbose output on standard output
    -f  specify archive file name
    -m  include manifest information from specified manifest file
    -e  specify application entry point for stand-alone application
        bundled into an executable jar file
    -0  store only; use no ZIP compression
    -P  preserve leading '/' (absolute path) and ".." (parent directory) components from file names
    -M  do not create a manifest file for the entries
    -i  generate index information for the specified jar files
    -C  change to the specified directory and include the following file
If any file is a directory then it is processed recursively.
The manifest file name, the archive file name and the entry point name are
specified in the same order as the 'm', 'f' and 'e' flags.

Example 1: to archive two class files into an archive called classes.jar:
       jar cvf classes.jar Foo.class Bar.class
Example 2: use an existing manifest file 'mymanifest' and archive all the
           files in the foo/ directory into 'classes.jar':
       jar cvfm classes.jar mymanifest -C foo/ .
```

Comment: I'm not really able to find a place in IntelliJ to include this I'm afraid

Comment: @MartinRindarøy Possibly helpful: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/defining-ant-execution-options.html